# How do I change the name of an Azure Resource Group?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

After the new model was implemented, all of my websites now belong to individual Resource Groups called "Default-Web-East" and all of my SQL databases belong to individual Resource Groups called "Default-SQL-East".

This is confusing to say the least.

I would like to rename the groups to have some semantic meaning.  I would also like to group the associated SQL database and Web Site in the same Resource Group.

However, I do not see anyway to do either.  Is this possible?

1) Rename the Resource Group?
2) Combine an existing SQL DB and Website together into one Resource Group?

Comment: I've significantly updated the answer to my question. Let me know if you run into any issues with it

Comment: You might want to vote for this feature here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/6017710-rename-resource-groups

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Edit:** You can't rename an Azure Resource Group.

What you can do is move your resources to a new Resource Group instead. Moving all resources in Resource Group A to Resource Group B is the poor man's rename.

Unfortunately not all resource providers let you move resources between resource groups, and some that do might have strings attached that only let you move resources under certain conditions.

For Azure Web Apps (previously called Azure Websites) you can currently only move all the websites related resources in a single invocation. That "all websites related resources" means all resource under the provider "Microsoft.Web". This includes all websites, app hosting platforms, and certificates that are in the source resource group.

---

**Via the portal**

When viewing a group's resources, you can use the "Move" tab
[image: Screenshot of resource group options in portal]

Clicking the "Move" tab will show something this, allowing you to choose or create a new group:
[image: The move tab in resource group on Azure portal]

**Via Azure Powershell**

The easiest way to do this is to use the Move-AzureRmResource powershell cmdlet.

The command would look like this:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <sourceResourceGroupName> | Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName <destResourceGroupName>
```

source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/

---

**Via Rest API**

The other way to do this is to use the MoveResource Rest API or with the [ArmClient](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/01/azure-resource-manager-client.html).

Here's the API call you'll want to make:

**POST**    `https://<endpoint>/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/moveResources?api-version={api-version}`

Where `{resourceGroupName}` is the source resource group.

I'm pretty sure the endpoint should be "https://management.azure.com", but if you use the [ArmClient](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/01/azure-resource-manager-client.html) the tool will just take care of the endpoint for you.

**Request Body:**

```
{
   "targetResourceGroup": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{targetResourceGroupNameName}",
   "resources":
   [  
     "/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{source}/providers/{namespace}/{type}/{name}",
     "/subscriptions/{id}/resourceGroups/{source}/providers/{namespace}/{type}/{name}"
   ]
}
```

---

Comment: Can you please given an example? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The [`Set-AzureResource` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn654578.aspx) states "You cannot use this cmdlet to change the resource group of a resource", and Groups do not appear to be resources themselves that can be modified. Can you elaborate on how to use `Set-AzureResource` to rename a Resource Group?

Comment: @BrantBobby You're right, my answer was incorrect.  I've fixed the answer now

Comment: @mark-anderson It sucks that your edit got rejected, but I've updated my answer with your suggestions. Thanks for the really useful edit!

Comment: Additional Note: SSL certificates aren't moved. Have to manually handle certificates.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the main answer, Azure Portal has a feature of moving the Resources that is allowed to be moved to a new Resource group.

1. Go to your Resource Group that has Resources you want to move to an existing or a new created Resource Group.
2. Select the one, multiple or all (1) Resources you want to move and click on the Move (2) bottom as shown in image. (you can select moving to Resources with in the same subscription or to another subscription) A third option if you need just to change the Region) see the the figure at the end.

[image]

3. It will ask you to chose which Resource Group to move to.

> Note: This process might take some time, be patient. When done, you
> will see that the resource disappear from the old one and will be
> found in the new one. That said some resources might be restricted
> from been moved to other resources.

[image]

Move (Fixing) only region

[image]