# BUG:: Azure Resource Groups Validation Rules NOT WORKING

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-group

[First of all, it is very sad that BizSpark susbcription do not have any technical support, even to inform a error like this :-(((  ]

Ok, well , the error, that occurs twice creating a VirtualMachine, so replicated:

```html
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "target": "resourceGroupName",
    "message": "The entity name 'resourceGroupName' is invalid according to its validation rule: ^[^_\\W][\\w-._]{0,79}(?<![-.])$."
  }
}
```

The reason, it is because my resource group is called _ReGr_MyName, 
**but IT ALREADY EXIST !!!** 
(indeed the rest of resources, like Public-Ip, Storage Accounts, etc, are already under that resource group)

so seems like validation rules are inconsistent across different resources

I can provide the Operation-Id or the TRacking-ID if necesary

But please, solve this short of issues, Azure should be an stable system

Answer (score 0):

> In general, avoid having any special characters (- or _) as the first or last character in any name. These characters will cause most validation rules to fail.

For detailed information, please check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/guidance/guidance-naming-conventions).

Since we can't edit the name of created resource group, you may need to create a new resource group and move the resources into it.

Here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268495/change-name-of-azure-resource-group) from Zain Rizvi.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the response,

I may sound angry, in sort of way I am,

"-" and "_" are not really special, they have been around us for long long time, you tell me that % or & are special, and maybe, you say me that "·" or "~" are special and agree. But "-" and "_" ??

Ironic aside, the thing is that:
 - I can create a resource group called _ReGr_MyName
 - I can create almost any resource under that _ReGr_MyName
 - I have been using this naming for long time

BUT I CAN NOT CREATE A VM UNDER SAME NAME !

Logic?
NO ONE
<br>
that I mean as a BUG

Comment: Thanks Steven for the response,  

I may sound angry, in sort of way I am,  

"-" and "_" are not really special, they have been around us for long long time, you tell me that % or & are special, and maybe, you say me that "·" or "~" are special and agree. But "-" and "_" ??   

Ironic aside, the thing is that:   
 - I can create a resource group called _ReGr_MyName  
 - I can create almost any resource under that _ReGr_MyName  
 - I have been using this naming for long time  

BUT I CAN NOT CREATE A VM UNDER SAME NAME !  

Logic?  
NO ONE  
   
that I mean as a BUG