# Rename resource group programmatically in Azure Python API

Tags: python, api, azure, naming, azure-resource-group

How can I, using the Azure Python API, rename an existing resource group?

I have thoroughly researched the example code and both official and unofficial documentation, but I can't find any mention of "rename".

Is this operation even supported?

Sample code highly sought after, but will take any hint!

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268495/change-name-of-azure-resource-group

Comment: In short, it is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot (at this point in time) rename resource group in Azure.